# How to Retrieve Data From Firebase Real-time in a FlatList(React Native)?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm unable to display the data retrieved in comments in FlatList.
What is the possible solution so that I can display all data from UsersData and display it in the FlatList in my render method?

**Firebase Database**

[image]

```
const comments = [
      {reply: 'Reply 1'},
      {reply: 'Reply 2'},
      {reply: 'Reply 3'}];
export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {
      comments: comments
    }
  }

componentDidMount() {

    var that = this

    firebase.database().ref('/UsersData').on('child_added', function (data) {

      var newData = [...that.state.comments]
      newData.push(data)
      that.setState({ comments: newData })

    })

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          contentContainerStyle={styles.paragraph}
          data={this.state.comments}//The Data is not passed properly  
          renderItem={({data}) => <Text>{data.val().name}</Text>}
               //It should be pas displayed here
         />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

consloe.log(newData) returns
[image: console]

Comment: Curious why the initial value of comments is the contents of const comments. Are you trying to update that info once the component is loaded? Can you add console.log(newData) and tell me what is says?

Comment: I have passed the values just for checking the list mapping

Comment: what happens after componentDidMount when you console.log(newData)?

Comment: Console returns data snapshots from firebase when we do console.log(newData)